# List of mathematical notation / abbreviations

Tags: glossaries, acronyms, nomenclature

In my article, I would like to create a section "Mathematical Notation" that lists all the arcane mathematical symbols I'm using.

This is similar to an index or a list of figures. An example of what I have in mind is given by the section "Standard Notations" in the [following book](http://www.math.cornell.edu/~hatcher/AT/ATpage.html).

I'm not aware of a standard way to do create such a list, however. Any recommendations?

*Disambiguation:* I'm not asking for a list of mathematical symbols and their LaTeX counterparts. Not that Google would listen to me.

Comment: If it's similar to an index, it's going to be alphabetized by entry.  If it's similar to a list of figures, it's going to be ordered by appearance in the manuscript.  Hatcher's list is neither.  Are you sure you want to do this programmatically?  A table will probably do the trick.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You could use the comprehensive [`glossaries`](http://ctan.org/pkg/glossaries) package, it's the successor of the [`glossary`](http://ctan.org/pkg/glossary) package by the same author.

[`nomencl`](http://ctan.org/pkg/nomencl) is a good alternative.

There are further packages for this purpose, such as [`glosstex`](http://ctan.org/pkg/glosstex) (related to `nomencl`) and [`gloss`](http://ctan.org/pkg/gloss) (using BibTeX).

Answer (score 3):

That looks like something closely analogous to the `description` environment, which I imagine would serve your purposes admirably.

For something a little fancier, you could put it into a `tabular` inside a `table` (potentially using [booktabs](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/booktabs/)) which is what I'm using right now for a table of acronyms, abbreviations and initialisms:

[image: a table of acronyms]

etc.

The benefit being that your nomenclature and corresponding meanings are clearly delimited, which is not the case in the book you referred to.

Comment: Note that unless you use something like `supertabular`, this method will not break the table across pages.

Comment: Thanks, I ended up using a plain tabular environment. I will accept the other answer, though, since this is the answer I originally sought.