# How to typeset mathematical symbols (with index, etc) always the same way and easily?

Tags: symbols, nomenclature

When I started to write my thesis I decided not to make things too complicated and to just type mathematical symbols each time they appear, like
`$V_{s1}$` or `${CV_{D,\, \mathrm{Si}}^{*}}$`

Now, finally I regretted and defined macros for each of them to

- avoid typing errors and typeset them always the same way
- make typing easier (by less characters to type and by being able to use the command completion feature of the editor.

Like that:

```
 \newcommand{\FZ}[1]{\textcolor{blue}{\ensuremath{#1}}\xspace}
 \newcommand{\CvDSi}{\FZ{CV_{D,\, \mathrm{Si}}^{*}}}
 \newcommand{\Vs}{\FZ{V_{\mathrm{s}1}}}
```

(the (missing) blue color will help me to see where something is still typset "by hand" and the blue text color surely will be removed for the final version).

**Questions:**

Is there a more elegant way to typeset complex mathematical symbols which have to be used 100 times in a thesis?

Is there a way to automatically create a list (table) of those symbols, maybe even with a link to the equation/page where they are defined?
There was a post naming several possible solutions: [List of mathematical notation / abbreviations](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/13497/list-of-mathematical-notation-abbreviations/13500#13500). I never used an index in LaTeX yet  - which one would be to prefer in my case?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

For the second question: I haven't checked out the alternatives, but [nomencl](http://ctan.org/pkg/nomencl) is what I've had experience with for making a list of symbols.

```
\newcommand{\Vs}[1]{\FZ{V_{\mathrm{s}#1}}}
\makenomenclature
```

somewhere in the preamble, plus something like

```
In some subspace $\Vs{1}$, something happens.\nomenclature{$\Vs{1}$}{A special subspace}
```

in the main body.

Use an editor or other tool (`latexmk`, `make`, etc.) that will automatically run the `makeindex` command for you, too. On TeXnicCenter with TeX Live 2010, we made a copy of the `LaTeX => PDF` build profile called `LaTeX => PDF (Nomenclature)` that runs `makeindex` each time, and uses the arguments `"%tm".nlo -s nomencl.ist -o "%tm".nls`. We don't normally use `makeindex` for anything but nomenclatures, though.

Answer (score 4):

In TeXnicCenter you can use the `makeindex` thing like this:

1. click on `build` and then on `define output profiles`
2. click to `add a new one`
3. only allow the `makeindex` to run
4. path to the executable: `C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\miktex\bin\makeindex.exe`
5. notice that step 4 you have to find where the `makeindex.exe` is on your computer
6. fill in --> `"%tm".nlo -s nomencl.ist -o "%tm".nls`     for the command line
7. run this new output profile twice
8. run one time your old build profile (`Latex to pdf`)
9. once you run two times the new build profile, you don't have to run it again, except if you make new entries