# Problem with the nomenclature?

Tags: nomenclature

I am trying to use the `nomencl` package. I am following an excellent
looking guide available here:

http://www.cs.brown.edu/system/software/latex/doc/nomencl.pdf

However, I can't for the life of me get even the most basic example
working despite the document building with no errors. This is the
basic example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nomencl}
\makenomenclature
\begin{document}
\section*{Main equations}
\begin{equation}
a=\frac{N}{A}
\end{equation}%
\nomenclature{$a$}{The number of angels per unit area}%
\nomenclature{$N$}{The number of angels per needle point}%
\nomenclature{$A$}{The area of the needle point}%
The equation $\sigma = m a$%
\nomenclature{$\sigma$}{The total mass of angels per unit area}%
\nomenclature{$m$}{The mass of one angel}
follows easily.
\printnomenclature
\end{document}
```

When I build this document (using Texmaker and MikTex 2.9), I get
a page with the equations and text. There are no errors or warnings
shown and it even creates an ".nlo" file with the correct information
inside. But no nomenclature.

Can anyone think of anything I have missed or should try?

Comment: Have you run `makeindex <filename>.nlo -s nomencl.ist -o <filename>.nls` which the documentation says is necessary?

Comment: You can also automate the `makeindex` run in TeXnicCenter with [these instructions](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/14704/3345).

Answer (score 18):

the original code you have posted seems to work also, if you run `pdflatex`, then `makeindex`, then `pdflatex` again. I have copied and pasted your example into a file named `n.tex`. Then, I did

```
pdflatex n.tex
makeindex n.nlo -s nomencl.ist -o n.nls
pdflatex n.tex
```

and it seems to work.

You may also  want to  check a more up-to-date version of the documentation (the one from CTAN):
[package page on CTAN](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/listofsymbols);
[documentation, linked from CTAN](http://www.laqee.unal.edu.co/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/nomencl/nomencl.pdf)

Comment: @ Jay ... I am working on window 7 not linux, and I am not able to do what you did ... Can you help me please ?

Comment: I don't use Windows, but certainly there must be a way to compile the PDF file, then run makeindex, and then compile again. Do you use TeXnicCenter? If you do you could follow Mike Renfro's instructions (see the comment on your post, he  mentioned you could check this: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/14704/3345)

Answer (score 5):

In windows you should run the following command in the command prompt:

```
makeindex <filename>.glo  -s  nomencl.ist  -o <filename>.gls
```

(I think that `.glo` and `.gls` can be `.nlo` and `.nls` instead).

To open the command prompt go to `Start Menu`, type `cmd` then enter.
use `cd <path>` to go to your working folder and type the command.

To make things easier I'd suggest to keep the `nomencl.ist` file in the working folder so that the `makeindex` command can find it.

Comment: @ Vagelis ... Thanks a lot. But can you tell me where can I find the file nomencl.ist ?

Answer (score 4):

Go to:

- Options,
- Configure TeXmaker,

then in the makeindex box add

```
%.nlo -s nomencl.ist -o %.els
```

to the end of whatever is already in the box, separated by a space.

I am using TeXmaker under Windows 8.1 and this worked for me, hopefully its helpful.

Comment: why do you put .els whereas the answer above from @Jay used .nls

Answer (score 2):

I've added the following user command:

```
pdflatex -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode %.tex|makeindex %.nlo -s nomencl.ist -o %.nls|pdflatex -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode %.tex|"C:/Program Files/Adobe/Reader 11.0/Reader/AcroRd32.exe" %.pdf
```

This executes:

- pdflatex -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode %.tex
- makeindex %.nlo -s nomencl.ist -o %.nls
- pdflatex -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode %.tex
- "C:/Program Files/Adobe/Reader 11.0/Reader/AcroRd32.exe" %.pdf (display pdf using adobe reader)

The last line can be removed or edited if another pdf reader is used.

Regards.

Comment: If you aren't changing anything not related to the nomenclature, this chain will still check for any changes. This can take up quite some (unneeded) time for large projects.

Comment: Ok, so running this line only makes sense if the nomenclature list has been edited. If not, just run pdflatex?

Comment: Yes. Same for bibliographies, if nothing bibliography related has changed, there is no need to run `bibtex` or `biber`.

Comment: Thanks!! I've just started using Latex today and it took me a lot of time to figure out how to implement a list of symbols. First I tries glossaries but that did not work (due to Perl problems). However, the nomenclature works great.

Comment: [LaTeX for complete novices](http://www.dickimaw-books.com/latex/novices/index.html) is a good read ;-)

Answer (score 1):

The answer of Adrian worked for me, with different settings.
Options > Configure TeXmaker > in the makeindex box:

```
makeindex %.idx %.nlo -s nomencl.ist -o %.nls
```