# Error: could not start the command in Texmaker when I run makeindex

Tags: errors, texmaker, mactex, nomenclature

I'm trying to create a nomenclature but I'm getting the following error when I run makeindex:

> Error: Could not start the command

This error appears even with this basic example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[refpage]{nomencl}

\makenomenclature

\begin{document}
Example of nomenclature \nomenclature{A}{Area}

\printnomenclature
\end{document}
```

In the Configure Texmaker editor I wrote: `makeindex %.nlo -s nomencl.ist -o %.nls` in the makeindex slot. Then I run:

1. PdfLaTeX
2. MakeIndex

And the error appears... I also tried all suggestions [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/62061/problem-with-the-nomenclature), but nothing seems to work.

I have installed MacTex 2012 distribution, Mac OS X 10.7.5

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look on [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.  Usually, we don't put a greeting or a “thank you” in our posts. While this might seem strange at first, it is not a sign of lack of politeness, but rather part of our trying to keep everything very concise. [Accepting and upvoting answers is the preferred way here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about) to say “thank you” to users who helped you.

Comment: Are you sure you have `makeindex` installed?

Comment: @karlkoeller how do I know if i have `makeindex` installed?

Comment: @MarioS.E. understood ;)

Comment: Which TeX distribution did you install, and in which OS?

Comment: @karlkoeller I installed MacTex 2012 distribution, Mac OS X 10.7.5

Comment: I'm not very familiar with them, but I think that `/usr/texbin/` should be a symbolic link to the executables directory. Have a look there.

Comment: @karlkoeller ok, I'll try to figure it out... Thanks for the suggestions! :)

Comment: Have you tried running `makeindex` from a [terminal](http://www.dickimaw-books.com/latex/novices/html/terminal.html) rather than via TeXmaker?

Comment: [Try reset the TeXmaker settings (Options" -> "Settings file" -> "reset settings) also verify at terminal `makeindex`.](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/117679/log-file-not-found-error-with-mactex-and-texmaker#comment261426_117679)

Comment: @NicolaTalbot thanks! how do I run makeindex in terminal?

Comment: @garuch [Open the Mac Terminal](http://www.dickimaw-books.com/latex/novices/html/terminal.html), then `cd` to the directory your document is in, then type `makeindex mydoc.nlo -s nomencl.ist -o mydoc.nls`, replacing `mydoc` with the base name of your tex file.

Comment: @NicolaTalbot Running it in terminal worked! Thanks!

Answer (score 14):

For some strange reasons, TeXMaker finds the path to pdflatex, but not the one to makeindex.

The best solution is to specify the full path to makeindex in the corresponding slot of the 'Configure TeXMaker' -> 'Commands' dialog, by writing

```
"/usr/texbin/makeindex" -s nomencl.ist -t %.nlg -o %.nls %.nlo
```

`-t %.nlg` has been added to generate a `.nlg` log file so that it can be distinguished from the normal `.ilg` log file that makeindex generates when creating indexes.

Pressing <kbd>F12</kbd> now you will be able to compile your nomenclatures.

If you now want to be able to perform the full compilation cycle and view your finished `.pdf` file by just pressing <kbd>F1</kbd>, you can configure your 'Quick Build' command, choosing the wizard in the 'Configure TeXMaker' -> 'Quick Build' dialog, and adding, in the following sequence:

> PdfLaTeX
>
> Makeindex
>
> PdfLaTeX
>
> Pdf Viewer

In this way one can achieve the same result obtainable with the arara tool (which is anyway a very nice tool) but without its need.

---

Now, if you press <kbd>F1</kbd> when your MWE is active, you obtain the following result:

[image: result]

Answer (score 6):

If I change the MakeIndex slot into

```
"/usr/texbin/makeindex" %.nlo -s nomencl.ist -o %.nls
```

doing "PDFLaTeX", then "MakeIndex" and again "PDFLaTeX" results in correct compilation.

If you have an updated distribution, you also have Arara. Edit the User commands; in a free slot add "Arara" as menu item and

```
"/usr/texbin/arara" -v %
```

in the second box, like in the following picture:

[image]

Then change your input as

```
% arara: pdflatex
% arara: nomencl
% arara: pdflatex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[refpage]{nomencl}

\makenomenclature

\begin{document}
Example of nomenclature \nomenclature{A}{Area}

\printnomenclature
\end{document}
```

and for compiling choose the just defined user command. You'll enjoy the experience. :)

Comment: I tried this with another document in which I was having the same problem and now it works! thanks a lot! :-)

Comment: +1 this is definitely the way to go- `arara` has solved so many of these types of problems :)

Answer (score 3):

I found a solution for `TeXnicCenter`:

The MakeIndex slot should be (see figure):

`"%tm.nlo" -s "nomencl.ist" -o "%tm.nls"`

[image]

And, of course, your file should look:

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}   
\usepackage[refpage]{nomencl}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\makenomenclature

\begin{document}
Example of nomenclature \nomenclature{A}{Area}

\printnomenclature

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

1) Be sure that make index is installed

2) For the makeindex command line in Texmaker, you should use :

> makeindex %.nlo -s nomencl.ist -o %.nls -t %.nlg

(see [here](http://www.xm1math.net/doculatex/nomenclature/nomenclature1.png) )

3) You can automatize the compilation by using the "user quick build command" or one of the "user" commands ("User" menu) : click on the "wizard" button at the end of the line and select the sequence :

> Pdflatex+MakeIndex+PdfLatex+View Pdf

Comment: I already tried your suggestions but they didn't work. When I run Pdflatex+MakeIndex+PdfLatex+View Pdf, I get the error... :'(

Answer (score 0):

Check if there is "@" in the filename or any other special symbol, for some reason beamer presentation was not working if there was @ in the filename, once removed all worked very smoothly.

All the other documentclass was working, so I knew that there is no problem in configuration.