# issues with generating a nomenclature with TexMaker

Tags: nomenclature

Im trying to write my thesis with TexMakerX and am using a latex template found at

http://www-h.eng.cam.ac.uk/help/tpl/textprocessing/ThesisStyle/

the problem is I can't reproduce the example shown. The pdf generated works great but it does not include the nomenclature as specified. I then look at an old version of the template which includes some advice on the nomenclature issue, found here:

http://www-h.eng.cam.ac.uk/help/tpl/textprocessing/ThesisStyleold/

and it is mentiones that the 'files should work ok with front-ends like Texnic, but to get nomenclature features, etc, working you'll need to set makeindex as a postprocessor'. So, I go to Tools and select 'MakeIndex', then I receive a message saying:

Process started: makeindex "thesis".idx

Input index file thesis.idx not found. Usage: makeindex [-ilqrcgLT] [-s sty] [-o ind] [-t log] [-p num] [idx0 idx1 ...]

Process exited with error(s)

What should I do?

Comment: You have to run `makeindex thesis.nlo -s nomencl.ist -o thesis.nls`

Comment: See this answer of mine about setting it in TeXMaker: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/118197/27635

Comment: @karlkoeller I have followed what you have shown in the link but I am still receiving an error. I copy the example shown in http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/118197/27635 and then select options -> Configure TexMakerX -> then in Commands -> Makeindex and then replace what was already written in the space with "/usr/texbin/makeindex" -s nomencl.ist -t %.nlg -o %.nls %.nlo and then save then click PdfLaTeX

Makeindex

PdfLaTeX

Pdf Viewer and I receive an error Error: Could not start the command: "/usr/texbin/makeindex" -s nomencl.ist -t "example".nlg -o "example".nls "example".nlo

Comment: Also, by typing makeindex thesis.nlo -s nomencl.ist -o thesis.nls into the command line works. Not sure why it fails when I try to do it TexMakerX though.

Comment: Replace "/usr/texbin/makeindex" with your path to `makeindex.exe`

Comment: Have you been able to set it to work in TeXMaker following my guidelines?

Comment: OK. So we can close this one as a duplicate of [Error: could not start the command in Texmaker when I run makeindex](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/117499/27635)