# Insert Abbreviations in LyX document

Tags: table-of-contents, lyx, acronyms

I would like to generate the abbreviations entry in the report written in LyX. I could not find it. I would like to know 3 things :

1. Insert the abbreviations table in the TOC.
2. Insert the Abbreviation list at the end of all chapters from the abbreviations defined.
3. Define the list of abbreviations as well.

Comment: Here are suggestions for LaTeX, which can be used with LyX too: [List of mathematical notation/abbreviations](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/13497/list-of-mathematical-notation-abbreviations).

Answer (score 5):

LyX directly supports the [`nomencl`](http://ctan.org/pkg/nomencl) package.

- In the main menu, choose the `Insert` menu and then `List/ToC`, `Nomenclature`.
- You can add nomenclature entries using also the menu, `Insert`, then `Nomenclature Entry`.

For further information have a look at the [`nomencl` documentation](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/nomencl/nomencl.pdf).

A very good alternative to `nomencl` is the [`glossaries` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/glossaries).