# Lyx and List of Acronyms

Tags: lyx, acronyms

I need to generate the List of Acronyms for a report class document, i used this method to make the acronym:

> insert -> nomenclature entry

then I write the symbol and the description. Example:

```
Symbol: API
Description: Application Programming Interface
```

But when I did this:

> insert -> List / TOC -> Nomenclature

in the place where I want the list of acronyms to appear nothing happens.

What am I doing wrong here, and how to insert an abbreviation table into my document?

#### Update:

I know about this [Question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/28796/insert-abbreviations-in-lyx-document?rq=1) but what I want is not an abbreviation table after each chapter; I want one in the beginning of the document after the table of contents.

Comment: I am not sure but try this:
add "\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Nomenclature}" at the position where you want to have your nomenclatur and afterwards the the list of all your acronyms. This should insert all acronyms at this position...

Comment: I think that's for adding an element to the table of content what I want is to add a table of abbreviation

Comment: I also just added acronyms with 
>insert -> nomenclature entry
but at the place where they should be displayed. I didn't used the second command you mentioned.
Update: I just tried it and it worked fine. I am not sure why you are using the second command...

Comment: What you mean it worked fine, did it generate a table of abbreviation?

Comment: Thanks, that did it `"Tools > Preferences > Output > LaTeX" set to "makeindex -s nomencl.ist"` maybe put this as an answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A "nomenclature entry" is translated by LyX to a `\nomenclature` command of the [package "nomencl"](http://ctan.org/pkg/nomencl). The creation of the list of acronyms by "Insert > List/TOC > Nomenclature" invokes the program "makeindex" (of the TeX distribution).

One can tweak the call of "makeindex" or could even replace it by changing the field "Nomenclature command" under "Tools > Preferences > Output > LaTeX". For LyX 2.0.x, the *default setting* of this field should be `makeindex -s nomencl.ist`. This value might have been lost somehow...