# List of notations and index, in order, from already-tagged sources

Tags: hyperref, indexing

My question is much like [List of mathematical notation / abbreviations](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/13497/list-of-mathematical-notation-abbreviations), but my situation is slightly different, in that I think I've done enough work on my document beforehand that the process could be partially automated if I were clever about it.

I've been making a thesis, and tagging each new definition and notation with a high-visibility macro as I go along (it's `\defd{}` for a definition and `$\defm{}$` for math mode, if anyone's keeping score).

These conventions will make it easier for my readers to isolate definitions and relocate them, but what I think might really help is having an index of terms and of notation. I don't think I want to gloss each term or symbol, but just to create a list of them along with and in order of first page occurrence, with hyperlinks if possible. Because I've been as religious as I've been in tagging these first occurrences, I feel like it should be pretty possible to automate the process of compiling these indices.

Is it possible? How could I do it?

Comment: Could you please add an example of your code and how your result should like look at the end?

Comment: What I want is something like this, except not requiring the "Meanings" column: https://c1.staticflickr.com/3/2052/5802613877_8fae2371b3_z.jpg.

I'm not sure what code you want. I've given in the question the macros I use to tag notations and defined terms; would it be helpful to have a list of the packages already being loaded?